# Python function sublist from input with while loop

Tags: python

My problem is this:  Write a function, sublist, that takes in a list of numbers as the parameter. In the function, use a while loop to return a sublist of the input list. The sublist should contain the same values of the original list up until it reaches the number 5 (it should not contain the number 5).

I tinker with it and I get the question partially correct sometimes.

```
def sublist(x):
    a = [int(x) for x in input()]
    while x < 5:
        x = x + 1
    return(x)
```

Comment: you need to build a new list in your while loop, and add data into that list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a `while` loop with a check on the number value, you'd better create a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python) from the input list and use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to iterate over it:

```
def sublist(x):
    sub = []
    x = (num for num in x)  # create a generator
    num = next(x, 5)  
    while num != 5:
        sub.append(num)
        num = next(x, 5)  # iterate
    return sub

x = [1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
sublist(x)

>>> [1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Is this a competition to solve the problem in as many different ways as possible _without_ a `while` loop? ☺ You might want to add an example with a `5` in it, too.

Comment: ahah..true story. sunday morning side effects. I will update

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
import itertools

def sublist(x):
    return list(itertools.takewhile(lambda n: n != 5, x))
```

**Update**: If this is a homework question, my answer won't work for you - but [nor should we just give you an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/1073696), so, look at `while` and `break`. Think about creating an empty list to start with, adding things to it until you need to stop, then returning it.

Comment: "reaches the number 5"; use `!=` instead of `<`.

Comment: Ah, good spot. I tested on a `range()` so it worked for me! I'll fix it.

Comment: question says "use a while loop"

Comment: @Chris_Rands _Technically_, `takewhile` has `while` in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  def sublist(lst):
    sub = lst
    for i in lst:
       if i == 5:
          x = lst.index(i)
          sub = lst[:x]
    return sub

  list3 = [1,56,34,2,3,1,4,5,5,5]
  sublist(list3)
```

---

I want to give an answer with using slicing and index method. that's very useful for Python beginners.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to write a function that takes every element of a list until the number 5 (e.g [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4]) then you could do that like this:

```
def sublist(input_list):
    output_list = []
    index = 0
    while index < len(input_list):
        if input_list[index] != 5:
            output_list.append(input_list[index])
            index += 1
        else:
            break
    return output_list
```

The while loop is broken when you reach 5. Until then, each value is added to a new list which is then returned by the function.

**Update:** Change while condition to check index is less than the length of the input list

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't understand the question.

> Write a function, `sublist`, that takes a list of numbers as the parameter.

This means that if we have this:

```
def sublist(x):
    pass
```

then `x` is going to be a `list` — *not*, as in your example, a number. Also, you don't need to do anything with `input()`; you've already got the list, so don't need that line at all.

> In the function, use a `while` loop to return a sublist of the input list.

Well, Python has a feature called ["generators"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) that let you do this *very* easily! I'm going to cheat a bit, and *not* use a `while` loop. Instead, I'll use a `for` loop:

```
def sublist(x):
    for num in x:
        if num == 5:
            # we need to stop; break out of the for loop
            break
        # output the next number
        yield num
```

Now this code works:

```
>>> for num in sublist([3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7]):
...     print(num)
3
4
2
>>>
```

However, `sublist` doesn't technically return a *list*. Instead, let's use some MAGIC to *make* it return a list:

```
from functools import wraps
return_list = lambda f:wraps(f)(lambda *a,**k:list(f(*a,**k)))
```

(You don't need to know how this works.) Now, when we define our function, we [decorate](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax) it with `return_list`, which will make the output a `list`:

```
@return_list
def sublist(x):
    for num in x:
        if num == 5:
            # we need to stop; break out of the for loop
            break
        # output the next number
        yield num
```

And now this also works:

```
>>> print(sublist([3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7]))
[3, 4, 2]
>>>
```

Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

```
def sublist(x):
    accum = 0
    sub = []
    while accum < len(x):
        if x[accum]== 5:
            return sub
        else:
            sub.append(x[accum])
        accum = accum +1
    return sub

x = [1, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8]
print(sublist(x))
```

Comment: Please add a description for your solution

Comment: In particular, when answering old posts with accepted answers, it's especially useful to not only explain your code, but _also_ explain why your approach might be preferable or more relevant than the established answer. Can you edit your answer to include that?

Answer (score 0):

```
def sublist(lst):


    output_list = []
    for i in lst:
        while i==5:
            return output_list
        output_list.append(i)
    return output_list
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I did this like that.

```
def sublist(x):
    count = 0
    new = []
    if 5 in x:
        while(x[count] != 5):
            new.append(x[count])
            count += 1
        return new
        
    else:
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sublist(num):
    list = []
    for x in num:
        if x == 5:
            break
        while x != 5:
            list.append(x)
            break
    return list

num = [1,2,4,6,7,8,9,5,1,3,4]
print(sublist(num))
```

Comment: This does not seem to provide anything new to the post when I check other answers, maybe adding a description about how does this solve the problem and in what way is it different or better than other answers might help.

Answer (score -1):

```
num = [1, 2, 3, 17, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 9]
new = []
def check_nums(x):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(x) and x[idx] != 7:
        print(idx)
        new.append(x[idx])
        idx += 1
    print(idx)
    return new
print(check_nums(num))
```

Comment: Giving an answer to an old question which already has an accepted answer is fine. However, in that case make it clear (explain) why your answer is "better" than the already accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889201/5698098) or the one which uses the [itertools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889113/5698098).

Answer (score -1):

```
def sublist(a):
    i=0;
    lst=[];
    while(i<len(a) and a[i]!=5):
        lst.append(a[i]);
        i+=1;
    return lst;
```